# Google Chrome Extension -- Declared icons in manifest.json won't load

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building my second chrome extension, and can't get the icons to load in development mode; everything is still a puzzle piece in chrome. I have triple-checked the path and that they are each the correct size. Any ideas on why they won't load? Here is the manifest.json

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Wishlist",
  "short_name": "Add things to your wishlist.",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Wishlist",
    "default_icon": "icons/16x16.png"
  },

  "icons": {
    "16": "icons/16x16.png",
    "48": "icons/48x48.png",
    "128": "icons/128x128.png"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your directory structure please.

Comment: Close `chrome://extensions`, then open it again, and voilà, the icons will be there.

Comment: @RobW tried that and it didn't work; also tried restarting chrome. Thanks though!

Comment: Can you zip the contents and put it online? Perhaps you really overlooked a small error in the filename.